# fusion table not updating

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

Using Google APIS Explorer I run the following query

```
update 1k_IHoD6ZblvZPkdgRapa3wyZcgYh1ug2L_aP_-s set 'NH' = 'test' where rowid = +'69048'
```

it returns

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

    {
    "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
    "columns": [
    "affected_rows"
    ],
    "rows": [
    [
    "1"
    ]
    ]
    }
```

However when I check my fusion table it's not been updated.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: How is it relevant to the tag "FusionCharts"?

Comment: The row with rowid 69048 does not seem to exist. At least when you try to select it, nothing is returned (see [the result from the Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=select+*+from+1k_IHoD6ZblvZPkdgRapa3wyZcgYh1ug2L_aP_-s+where+rowid+%253D+'69048'&_h=1&)).